# How do I create a batch file that pings first a random computer in the network and then copy something on the server?

Tags: batch-file, ping, robocopy

I am trying to copy a file from a client to the server. It should be a dynamic client path and the server path is static. My first thought that I ping every Client in the network and if available copy the files. I also have a list of all the clients, but is it possible that i can create a "dynamic" list of all active clients in the network and then start copying?

```
robocopy \\"gis30"\d$\outlook\%username% \\saturn\o_outlook\%username% *.pst /e /xo /r:1 /w:10 /L
```

"gis30" should be the dynamic name of a client

Comment: Is the script running from the client side or server side?  Is it possible that Outlook will be running on the client machine at the time the script runs?

Comment: It runs on the server side and it would maybe possible that Outlook runs on the client.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to user robocopy when Outlook is running on the client.  Outlook holds an exclusive lock on the file that makes it impossible for other programs to copy it.  Also, using ping to see if a machine exists is likely going to find devices that are not user computers.  It would be better to test the existence of the PST file.  Something like `if exist \\ip_address\d$\outlook do ...`.  However using `%username%` won't work either because you need the username of the user on the client PC, not the user running on the server...

Comment: You could enumerate the folders under `\\ip_address\d$\outlook` and see if anyone has a pst file.  That's a bit more complicated however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of working i finally got it working. So here if anybody else needs an similar code here it is:

```
@echo off

set x=1

:loop1
if %x%==9 goto loop2
robocopy \\gis0%x%\d$\outlook\ \\saturn\o_outlook\ *.pst /e /xo /w:0 /r:0
set /a x=%x%+1
goto loop1

:reset
set x=10

:loop2
if %x%==99 goto ende
robocopy \\gis%x%\d$\outlook\ \\saturn\o_outlook\ *.pst /e /xo /w:0 /r:0
set /a x=%x%+1
goto loop2

:ende
```